# Usage of 'will' twice in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is the sentence 'The student who will score the maximum marks will win a prize' correct?

Answer (score 4):

A more idiomatic way to phrase it would be 'The student **who scores** [the] maximum marks will win a prize".

*Highest marks* is probably more usual than *maximum marks*.

Comment: The first version might work out cheaper.